# Do I need to delete uploaded files if I only want to parse them

Tags: forms

I'm building an upload form for uploading files which are only parsed, and don't need to stay on the server.

I have this code:

```
$validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('xml'));
$file = file_save_upload('file', $validators);
```

After which I parse the file.

As I understand it, it saves in tmp by default. Now if I don't do anything else but parse that file, will Drupal or the OS discard the temporary file automatically or do I need to do something else in my code to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for [file_save_upload()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal!includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7) the file will be registered as a temporary file, so that it will be deleted anyway, assuming you have cron running on a regular basis.

> "The file will be added to the {file_managed} table as a temporary file. Temporary files are periodically cleaned. To make the file a permanent file, assign the status and use file_save() to save the changes."

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the file stored in you temp folder, i think its a standard specially if your uploading big files. you may use the ff:

```
drupal_unlink($uri);
```